# Set Spinner Title from firebase db

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I want to show title in spinner 1 (spinner 2 data from local and spinner 1 data from firebase), How can I do that

[image]

```
mProjectName = findViewById(R.id.projectNameRegister);
    listSpinner = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<>(RegisterActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listSpinner);
    mProjectName.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
    referenceSpinner = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ListProjects");


private void retrievedData() {
    listenerSpinner = referenceSpinner.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String project = item.child("projectName").getValue().toString();
                listSpinner.add(project);
            }
            adapterSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As far as you are pulling and rendering data you can add spinner before calling retrievedData();

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?